# Is the order of function definitions important for inlining in C++

Tags: c++, inline

When one function calls another, and inlining is desired, is the **order** of the definitions of the two functions important? Assume that the two definitions occur in the same translation unit.

I am primarily interested in what the C++ standard says about it, if anything. However, if you have important information about the inlining behavior in specific compilers, I would be interested in that too. Please assume that no link-time optimization occurs (is disabled).

Specifically, are the following two versions equally likely to achieve inlining according to the C++ standard?

Version one:

```
inline void foo() { ... }
void bar() { ... foo(); ... }
```

Version two:

```
inline void foo();
void bar() { ... foo(); ... }
void foo() { ... }
```

EDIT: Please note that this question is **not** about the effectiveness of the `inline` keyword with respect to achieving inlining in general. I specifically ask about whether the standard says anything about the **order** of function definitions in relation to achieving inlining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't make any imposition here. Compilers are free to inline or not in any situation they see fit. The inline keyword may have no effect other than allowing multiple definitions of the same function.

Most compilers will be able to inline any function that is available to the translation unit, regardless of the order it appears in the source. Forward declarations generally only affect what names are available at a given point in the source file, not anything about the final output of the binary.

Comment: So you are saying, that the C++ standard assigns equal preference to the two versions with respect to achieving inlining. How sure are you?

Comment: No, it assigns no preference. The inline keyword is merely a suggestion. The only thing `inline` is guaranteed to get you is the ability to have the same function definition show up multiple times.

Comment: Forget about the `inline` keyword. Are you sure that the standard assigns absolutely no preference to any of the two orders? A simple "yes" will suffice! :-)

Comment: The only restriction I managed to figure out from the Standard is: 7.1.2.4. If the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed

Comment: @YurySchkatula I have now searched through the C++11 standard, and I cannot find anything either, so I'll declare this answer as _accepted_.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege: be aware that there's a huge difference between "assigning equal preference" and "assigning no preference". If the standard said that the two would either both be inlined or neither would, then that's a constraint on implementations. No such constraint exists. So if an implementation only inlines your first example, the standard is satisfied. For that matter, if an implementation only inlines your second example, the standard is satisfied.

Comment: @SteveJessop Perfect answer, especially the last sentence. Thanks.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege: oh, and the way we can be reasonably sure that the standard says nothing on the subject, without checking every clause, is that the standard doesn't even define what "inlining" is. Even the hint part of `inline` is worded as a hint to optimize for "fast calling of the function" (or similar wording). Code inlining is of course the most common such optimization, but the standard deliberately pretends that it doesn't know that, to leave actual optimization techniques entirely in the hands of the implementor.

Answer (score 4):

In reality the `inline` keyword has less to do with inlining code and more to do with allowing "legal violation" of the one definition rule. The main purpose of `inline` is to tell the compiler that a function may appear in multiple translation units (and that it will have the same definition in each one). This allows it to avoid multiple definition errors at the link stage.

Using the `inline` keyword is no guarantee that the compiler will inline the function at all - it's just a suggestion. Additionally many compilers will inline functions not marked as `inline` if the definition can be seen within the translation unit and the compiler deems it worthwhile. I strongly suspect that both examples you gave would both be inlined or not by a particular compiler.

In short, let the compiler decide whether or not to inline, and write your code in the most readable way.

Comment: I am not so interesting in details on the connection of the `inline` keyword to inlining in general. Would you happen to know whether the standard makes any notes about which order is best when inlining is desired.

Comment: Actually, I vaguely remember that the standard does say something about it, but I am not sure. I'd love to hear from someone who have studied the standard with this question in mind.